# NSSM for Selenium Server (Paused)

Tags: java, services, selenium, grid

My selenium grid server is working very well when im running it on cmd and then java -jar selenium-server-.jar standalone and I can also run my test side files from my monitoring. But when I close the CMD the app will be shut off. Im trying to keep Selenium Server running 24/7 So I can monitor my test cases. So I found nssm to run java -jar selenium-server-.jar standalone as services. After creating the services via nssm the services will not starting up (paused)

Can someone help me out with this. Is there a better way to fix this?

Only what I want is a running selenium grid server while im logged out on the server.